# Does dio package in flutter uses isolates for decoding json?

Tags: flutter, dart, dio

I just wanted to know, if the dio packages uses isolates by default, if it do not uses isolates than how can I use them. because my API fetches a lot of data and decoding the json on UI thread might not be a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dio has a plugin called *dio_flutter_transformer* that is especially for Flutter and will parse Json in a separate Isolate via the compute function.

Take a look at the Dio package on pub to see the list of plugins available:

https://pub.dev/packages/dio

Answer (score 4):

No, it does not use isolate by default.

If you want to parse json in an isolate, you can use flutter [compute function](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/compute.html) to run it in an isolate.

You can find an example of using this in the example app of dio: [lib/main.dart#L16](https://github.com/flutterchina/dio/blob/5e3eb797a4202b9aca0acc74d325c10523b79584/example/flutter_example/lib/main.dart#L16)